# Need pointing to sources of information regarding Schedules Direct data requests

Tags: rest, soap, xbmc, epg

I am developing an add-on for XBMC to pull U.S. and Canada scheduling data for an EPG. Currently, there are several PVR's, several techniques and means to obtain data from, it seems, everywhere except the U.S. and Canada.

I've found a service (in alpha testing) that will provide the information for a modest $25/year fee. It's called Schedules Direct (http://www.schedulesdirect.org).

The add-on will query Schedules Direct to obtain the program data, then slice & dice the data returned into a suitable form for XBMC to utilize. I am seeking documentation on the formats for data requests to Schedules Direct, as well as the specifications for the returned data formats.

Can anyone help who has encountered this problem before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MythTV successully accesses and processes data from SD. Have a look at the [mythfilldatbase command](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Mythfilldatabase) and code to [see how they do it](http://code.mythtv.org/trac/browser/mythtv/mythtv/programs/mythfilldatabase).

Answer (score 0):

The developer's forum at Schedules Direct [(here)](http://forums.schedulesdirect.org/viewforum.php?f=8)  has sample code and schema documentation.

You can also view source code for most of the approved applications.

If there are currently XBMC PVRs that can read XMLTV formatted data, you can use the XMLTV.ORG tv_grab_na_dd grabber to convert Schedules Direct data to XMLTV.

Robert